# Traveling from JFK to Manhattan with 6 bags

Tags: trains, airport-transfer, new-york-city, taxis, jfk

Me and my friend will be relocating to US. We will land at New York City JFK at about 8am and our destination is in Manhattan. I am aware of transportation options like Yellow Taxi, Uber, Metros. Since each of us will have three 23kg bags (L+W+H is 165 cm):

I am wondering what is the most economical and comfortable way to travel. Whether Yellow Taxi can even fit these bags along with two passengers? Or he will charge extra?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With that much luggage, the train or the subway isn't really practical; there's just no way to carry that much and lug the bags up/down steps and escalators.

I'd probably just take a taxi. It's a flat rate, so you know what you're getting into, where Uber will charge you partially based on time, with an additional charge for a large vehicle. As Michael Hampton says, it is [$52+tolls+tip](http://www.nyc.gov/html/tlc/html/passenger/taxicab_rate.shtml) from JFK to anywhere in Manhattan (so plan closer to $65 or so). When you get to the taxi rank at the airport, there will be an attendant there in charge of the line. Show the attendant your large amount of luggage; they'll either make sure you can squeeze it all into a standard cab or make sure you get one of the larger vans. There's no extra charge for luggage.

Expect significant traffic at that time of day. Google Maps estimates between 0:55-1:55 from JFK to Midtown leaving at 8:30am on a weekday (I would expect the higher end end of that range).

Comment: 1:55 at 8:30 am is a better estimate

Comment: If this is a weekday then @Karlson is right. Expect a 2 hour trip to your location. You may be lucky and get there in an 1:45. :-)

Comment: I arrived there with a large sports luggage. The taxi rank attendant have a good understanding about sizes and flags down a larger cab via radio (He might just ask you to wait next to the line till 'your' cab arrives)

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking your best solution with the amount of luggage you're carrying is to use a Taxi or an Uber.  You can try to get your luggage to Airtran and then to the Subway (either E or an A train) but you have to figure out how you can 6 bags up and down the escalators and/or stairs.

For the Taxi the situation is simple.  At every taxi stand in JFK there is a dispatcher, which may simply call up a minivan or an SUV cab for you so you can fit all your belongings.

The fee for Taxi is [$52](http://www.panynj.gov/airports/jfk-taxi-car-van-service.html) plus tolls, tips, and possible other surcharges (see the linked page)

Uber will probably run you higher for the SUV or a Black Car but you can look at that option too.  I can't seem to get an estimate for that.  UberPool estimates $35 but I don't think you can share a ride to get that rate.